# Java calling variable in another method

Tags: java, variables, io, bufferedreader

I'm new to Java programming, I just have a easy question but I can't do it because I didnt know how to write it on Java. Thanks in Advance.

I want to call variable values in another method.

```
public static void ReadIN() throws Exception{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
        String line = null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          String[] values = line.split(","); // want to be call
          for (String inputIN : values) {
          inputIN = values[2];
          }
        }


        br.close(); 
      }


      public static void checkStatus() {

        // call variable 'values' here

      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you exactly need. Anyway try this:

```
public static void readIN() throws Exception{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
    String line = null;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] values = line.split(","); // want to be call
        for (String inputIN : values) {
            inputIN = values[2];
        }
        checkStatus(values);
    }
    br.close(); 
}


public static void checkStatus(String[] values) {
    // call variable 'values' here
    System.out.println(values);
}
```

btw following the naming convention.

Edit: the following code should compile successfully, in Test.java

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test.readIN();
    }

    public static void readIN() throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
        String line = null;    
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] values = line.split(",");
            Test.checkStatus(values);
        }
        br.close(); 
    }


    public static void checkStatus(String[] values) {
        // call variable 'values' here
        System.out.println(values);
    }
}
```

Comment: so what do you exactly want?

Comment: I got errors, required : String[]
found : no arguments
reason :  actual and  formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: If you declare the method `checkStatus` as  `public static void checkStatus(String[] values)` then each time you call `checkStatus` you need a `String[]` parameter. So make sure you are writing something like `checkStatus(values)` not `checkStatus()`

Comment: Yes, I'm calling it on my main method as my obj.checkStatus(values);

Comment: See the edit. In fact I don't think there would be a compilation error. Please check if you really declare and call the method correctly. Try to compile my newly added code and see if there is still a problem.

Comment: This one is compiled smoothly! Thanks for this one, I can compare now the variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't access method variables outside the method that owns them. If the variable belongs directly to a class, the variables can be accessed by other methods.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! It gives me a clear understanding on accessing variables.

Comment: Sure thing. If it is what you were looking for, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call variables like that. One way you can do is to declare the variable values globally (Outside of your main or any other functions and right at the top below your packages and imports). This way all other functions will be able to use the variable values. Another way is to call the checkStatus function from main sending the variable values. Example below

in main function:

```
checkStatus(values);
```

Call the function checkStatus passing the variable values. JAVA is a strict pass by value only language. What happens is that the function checkStatus is called and a copy of the variable values is created with the same values in it and passed to the function.

function:

```
public static void checkStatus(String[] values) 
{
    // call variable 'values' here
    // Here you can make use of the variable values
}
```

---

If you plan to modify the variable values in the function checkStatus and want it to be modified in main altogether then you can either return the values back to main like so.

in main

```
String[] receive;
receive = checkStatus(values);
```

in the function:

```
public static String checkStatus(String[] values) 
{
     //Once you are done with your codes
     return values;
}
```

Hope this helps. please do comment if you need further clarification or help.

Comment: I just need to get the value of variable 'values' from method ReadIN and I'm going to create a function in method checkStatus to compare it to something..

Comment: then you don't need to use the return method. Just use the method i posted on top of my answer. Just send the value over and use it for comparison. Because you can't access the variable values from ReadIN without first sending the value from ReadIN to checkStatus. Or like i said you can always make values a global variable so that all other functions can access it.

Comment: same error bro - required : String[] found : no arguments reason : actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: May i know what is the purpose of this codes here `for (String inputIN : values) {
          inputIN = values[2];
          }`

Comment: String inputIN variable, FOREACH loop, foreach values will be stored in inputIN, but i'm just getting the index[2]